# How to Add a Menu Without a Bar

Tags: android

I've seen a lot of applications
There is no actionbar
But there is menu how?
like this picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4DcD.png)
How can I create this

Comment: Yes,
You can use PopMenu by which you can display Menu with out action bar.

Comment: Do I create onCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: If you will create Option menu then how you will call CreateOptionMenu pragmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

learn more ^

```
public void Noactionbar(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
}
```